# How to set Eclipse Java version in OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When I download and expand Eclipse EE version a file of type Application is created :

[image]

I'm new to using to Eclipse on MAC. I want to set the java version to

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"
```

But no eclipse.ini file is created. How to set and or install Eclipse on MAC and set the java version ?

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct variable path? Mine is `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Answer (score 3):

This solution allows you to specify the JVM for a given eclipse installation, without changing any system properties. Make sure you have a valid JVM (usually JDK 8 for eclipse) installed.

Here are the steps:

- open finder and navigate to the location of Eclipse (i.e. Applications)
- right-click on the eclipse application
- select "show package contents"
- navigate to `/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`
- open the .ini with a text-editor
- at the top of the file, add the following lines (or replace the existing -vm line)

> ```
> -vm
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
> ```

You need to replace `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk` with the name of your JVM.

Comment: And make sure this flag is before `-vmargs`

Answer (score 1):

File type "Application" is actually a directory.  Right-click it (or control click) and select "Show Package Contents".  You should find eclipse.ini at `Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` inside the Eclipse application directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the full JDK rather than the JRE before you can use it with Eclipse. The full JDK should set itself as the current Java. The JDK installs in something like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home`

As mentioned in the other answer the Eclipse application is actually a directory (called `Eclipse.app`) using 'Show Package Contents' in Finder will show you the contents.